# how to avoid re-compiling an npm package?

Tags: npm, npm-cache

- in my pipelines, i regularly have to call `npm ci`
- some npm packages require compilation (e.g. pg-native, node-rdkafka)
- compilation is slow

how can I make the second call to `npm ci` avoid compiling again?

- i have tried calling `npm install -g pg-native` first, but `npm ci` still recompiles
- in the past i used `peerDepdendencies` as a workaround, but that no longer appears to work (from npm version 7, i believe)

is it possible for an app to use a compiled cached dependency?